# how to create a java abstract class list of subclass objects

Tags: java, list, abstract-class

I have an abstract class, `carowners`. and two sub classes `person` and `company`.
Abstract class `carowners` have fields:

- name
- address
- next(to reference next object(`person` or `company`)) .

I need a list of `carowners` , where the objects in the list will either be a `Person` object or a `Company`- object (and indirect objects of type `CarOwner` ) .
I know how to create a `Linkedlist` or `ArrayList` of type `CarOwners`, But its not my requirement. i need a abstractclassi.e carowners list that stores person and company objects, each objects refers to another using next in abstract class.

Comment: It's unclear, what you are asking

Comment: What *is* your requirement?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: What *bleep* professor puts a bloody *next* field on an abstract data type that isn't a collection itself? Is he still stuck using C?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to store all instances of a `CarOwner` that are created, regardless of whether they are `Person` objects or `Company` objects. This *could* be achieved like this:

```
abstract class CarOwner
{
    private static final List<CarOwner> allCarOwners = new ArrayList<CarOwner>();
    public static List<CarOwner> getAllCarOwners()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(allCarOwners); 
    }

    CarOwner()
    { 
        CarOwner.allCarOwners.add(this);
    }
}

class Person extends CarOwner { }
class Company extends CarOwner { }

// To be used with
Person peson0 = new Person();
Person peson1 = new Person();
...
Company company0 = new Company();
Company company1 = new Company();

List<CarOwner> all = CarOwner.getAllCarOwners();

// Prints person0, person0 ..., company0, company1....
System.ut.println(all);
```

However, IF this is what was asked for, it is somewhat questionable, because it is something like a built-in memory leak.